# How to arrange images at middle of vertical using css?

Tags: css

I have one issue.

Images have different size.

I need to arrange in the middle of vertical.

[image]

The link of Images is changed dynamically.

And I don't wish to use line-height.

Is there a best and popular way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **CSS Flexbox**. Make your parent a flex container & in your image use `align-self: center`.

```css
.img-holder {
  display: inline-flex;
  background: black;
}

img {
  align-self: center;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-holder">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="image" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x60" alt="image" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x70" alt="image" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x30" alt="image" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x20" alt="image" />
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Its my pleasure @Eric